# db logic: best based in application or stored procedures?

Tags: sql, database

What are the advantages of using stored procedures versus embedding business logic in an application's code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are storing the business logic as a stored procedure and/or trigger you are putting a central fence around the data and controlling what rules determine what is stored and calculated in the database. If something changes you only have to change it in one place.

In keeping rules in a database a DBA can insist that all changes to data be made through one set of stored procedures. But invariably rules are also enforced through triggers, which while powerful, can slow down a database. An ideal (sic) system would have two instances/databases one of which maintains and enforces the rules and through messaging (SQL Server Service Broker or Rabbit are two popular programs) send the data that passes muster to a data store that is considered the Golden Copy.

The security in a database can be very tight so only certain, authorized users, can implement and maintain rules.

If you put the logic in code you may have to change the code in more then one place and for example if you change a rule about updating accounts you may (unless you have a very tight object model) have to remember to change the rule in multiple places and possibly version and distribute the new version. On the other hand the load is distributed to not only the database machine.

What frequently happens is that a developer further down the chain duplicates rules (such as checking for existing accounts)   and later when asked to add a rules adds it to where they have their sets of rules not at the top so only part of the app is covered by this new set of rules.

The ideal system is a three tier one in which the client has a sub-set of the rules and before data is stored, the data base reapplys the rules before sending the data to a data store.